# Ruby on cygwin - Permission denied

Tags: ruby, gcc, permissions, cygwin

I am trying to run gcc from a ruby script and it gives me an error which says Permission denied.
It works fine when running it right from the commandline and that makes me clueless why it won't work from ruby.
I can call other commands like "ls" from within Ruby.

I also tried setting the file permissions of gcc to 777 as well as making my user-account the owner of that file.

Here is my shell output:

```
Administrator@dominicgraec8aa ~
$ gcc
gcc: no input files

Administrator@dominicgraec8aa ~
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> `gcc`
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - gcc
        from (irb):1:in ``'
        from (irb):1
irb(main):002:0> `ls`
=> ""
```

I hope anyone has an idea on this.

Comment: Is ruby a non-cygwin program ? or did you install it as part of cygwin ?

Comment: Hey man, ruby is non-cygwin. I'll have to try the cygwin version.

Comment: In the case, it's probably a path problem as ruby is using windows paths and cygwin paths are posix. Might want to check that out.
Other things I can thing of: acl rights.
Did you try calling gcc from some C or any other bin or script in cygwin to see if you still get the same error ?

Comment: Just curious, is there a specific reason you must use the cygwin version? Because, if not, you could try installing the MinGW toolchain, which is a bit nicer. Or you could use the [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) ruby installation, and take the extra steps to install their [DevKit](http://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit/) which should give you a working gcc and, at the same time, allow you to build native C extensions when installing gems.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience it doesn't matter what path separator you use in Ruby on Windows as they both should work (and as they both work on the command line as well). When working with two different environments (Native Windows and Cygwin) it is good to make sure that you know which version you are running, since they are not necessarily compatible with each other.

I've had no problems running the native Windows versions of the Ruby toolchain, even using Pik too (like RVM for Windows), and I find it much simpler than having to manage two environments.